# Attempting to check in code through TFS results in "Value was either too large or too small for a UINT32" error message

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2015

When attempting to check in code through TFS in visual studio 2012 or 2013 sometimes results in displaying an error message "Value was either too large or too small for a UINT32" error message. What is causing this, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the dialog. This seems to consistently happen when you try to check in code that hasn't been saved, confusing the feature to a sufficient degree to throw up its hands in the air with this error.

The solution is simple: save your files before committing them.

Comment: I can think of a different solution. :-)

Comment: So can I, but that was pointy hairishly rejected

Comment: Thanks for that one, it appears the same occurs for an unsaved file that is not even part of the solution... I just had to close it and everything went fine.

Comment: You was right, I just edited my file during review and get this error. Saving helps for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well, I had a T-SQL editor window open which, unsaved, caused me to not be able to check in my pending changes.

Comment: File > Save All

Comment: In my case I was actually just trying to queue a new build without any checking-in going on. Never would've thought of this, thanks.

Comment: @ardave What different solution was that?

Comment: @KonradViltersten not using TFS

Comment: @ardave Hehe, that answers my follow-up question on the pointy-hairness of the decision.

Comment: This happens also when checking in files different from those that were'nt saved.

Comment: FYI: Error still happens in VS2015 Update 1.

Comment: Funny thing is this error still happens in VS 2015 Update 2 with the Git tooling. Anyway, saving all my files before checking in does the job. Thanks!

Comment: Get this when shelving in VS2017 with TFS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Another possible Scenario: this happens after reverting to older file versions from TFS and then changing a file and trying to checkin.

**Solution :** update to latest version before checkin

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/503357)

Comment: updated the solution , to be clearer